# Change Column Name Type, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, import-from-excel

I am Importing MS Excel File with below columns 
County, Country Name, Indicator, Indicator Name, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003
to Dataframe

```
Data = Data = pd.read_excel('File Path')

Data.columns.str.upper() -- Will give NAN for Integer column names

Data.loc[:, ~Data.columns.str.contains('Name:')] -- TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'Index'
```

Source File Location: http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/India_PSR_excel.zip

How to change column name to string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter `na=False`:

```
Data.loc[:, ~Data.columns.str.contains('Name:', na=False)]
```

Comment: works thanks, Here, Data.columns.str.upper() for integer it gives NAN

Comment: @SPy - yes, there is different functions - by default text functions return `NaN`s, but str.contains returned boolean mask, so different aproach - parameter `na`. Similar parameter is used in [`startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and `endswith` functions.

Comment: Ok, got it... If we want to change column name touppercase what is the alternative from Data.columns = Data.columns.str.upper()?

Comment: @SPy - ya, it is good solution, alternative is only list comprehension like `Data.columns = [x.upper() for x in Data.columns]`

Comment: [x.upper() for x in Data.columns] - Gives error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'upper'

Comment: `Data.columns = [str(x).upper() for x in Data.columns]`